# Motor torque when lowering a mass at constant velocity through a pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, torque

The motor is connected to the pulley via a gear with power efficiency $N_g$. When lifting the load at rated velocity gives me a motor torque $M_g$, which is a standard calculation.

But my problem now is, when lowering the same load at the same rated linear velocity, the motor torque is given as $M_g \cdot N_g^2$. Shouldn't it still be the same as $M_g$, since the forces are still the same only direction has changed. So I guess I am missing something here. Please help.